# Observable Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, observable

Hi I have this epic in my code and its work fine its fetch all data what i want. But when i want to test it i will get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined` I found this problem on the web but usually there is missing `return observabel` but i have it there ... Can you help me please?

```
const createMyEpic = ({
  actionID,
  endpoint, 
  callback, 
}: Props): Epic =>
  (action$: any, { api, getState }: Deps): CommonAction => action$.ofType(actionID)
    .mergeMap((epic: EpicMessage) => { 
      const {
        parameters,
        requestConfiguration = {},
      } = epic;
      const data = {

      };
      const method = epic.method || 'get'; 
      const configuration = {
        ...requestConfiguration,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:9000',
        },
      };

      return Observable.fromPromise( 
        api[method](
          parameters,
          data,
          configuration,
        ),
      ).map(callback);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could have something to do with that you are missing a return statement in your `.mergemap()`.

When using arrow function with `{...}` You need to have a return statement. e.g. `.mergemap((data) => { ... return something;})`. But if you are using arrow function without curlies, you should get away with returning Observable without actually having any return statement.

Hope it helped.

Comment: its help ... but it was not in this part of my code